# ERROR 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306'(111 "Connection refused")

Tags: networking, python, mysql, raspberry-pi

My laptop for database and raspberry pi 3b+ as remote computer:
[image: My laptop for database and raspberry pi 3b+ as remote computer]

I am trying to have a remote database from my laptop. I want my raspi 3b+ to connect to it but it seems I can't do it. Badly need your help. I will try to show here the flow I am trying to.

Flow I need to do: Fingerprint data > raspberry pi > database[localhost/xampp] > websystem > output.

The code is working on my laptop itself. I can input data. But when I'm trying to do the same thing to my raspi 3b+. It's now working and I don't know solution at all. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Why do you think `localhost` would just work when you are now accessing from another host instead? In addition to what (IP / hostname) you use on the client side (the Pi), the server would need to listen on an IP (or listen "unspecifically") that the client can reach as well.

Answer (score 0):

On your SQL Workbench, Add another user account on "Users and Privileges" with a different Host. For example: Set your "Limit to Hosts Matching" to something like "testhost" then set the administrative roles to "DBA".

After that's done, modify your connection code.
example:

```
try:
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='testhost', db=test, user=root, passwd='')
```

it should connect without any problems.